# In Elmish/Elmish.WPF, This construct causes code to be less generic .... The type varable 'a has been constrained to be type 'Msg'

Tags: f#, elmish, elmish-wpf

This statement in the update:

```
let update m msg =
  match msg with
  | SetEncounterMsg encounter ->
      match encounter with   
      | None -> init() , Cmd.none
      | Some s ->
          init () |> (fun q -> {q with Encounter = Some s}),
          Cmd.ofMsg (RequestPrescriptionsForEncounterMsg s)
```

runs/works correctly to request an asynchronous operation.

However, the  "RequestPrescriptionsForEnconterMsg" is giving the warning that "**This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type vairable 'a has been constrained to be type 'Msg'**

Why? This is of type Msg. How do I fix this? (I think I'm missing something here :(  )

Any help is most appreciated.

Edit #1:
The model, m, is initialized in the above with:

`let init () : Model` = .....

which is then being further updated by the function, fun.

Comment: Where do you use the variable `m`?

Comment: @phoog Plese see above edit. The Model, m, is initialized with init().

Comment: Please share a link to a GitHub repository with code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: There's no type annotation (type variable `'a`) in the code you've shown, so I suspect you haven't given us enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @BrianBerns  I aggree! However, I have used this exact same pattern in Elmish.wpf before without any warning messages--and this particular warning message gives me no idea where to look for the problem. I am curious to find out that maybe if I redefine init() to take the current Model, m, as a parameter as opposed to recreating the Model as it is currently defined, if that may not fix the error. I will try this in a bit to see if it makes a difference.  Anyway, it does run fine without error--so I'm tempted just to ignore it.